# Transform foreach to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collections, both contain objects.

First one is `IList` and the second one is `Dictionary`.

I need to traverse through IList and if the condition is filled then activate method from the certain object which is stored in `Dictionary`.

The current situation is like this:

```
 foreach (MyObject mo in MyListOfObjects)
 {
      if (mo.Active == myStatus.Enabled)
      {
           DictList[mo.ID].Start();
      }
  }
```

So far i've done this:

```
var r = MyListOfObjects.Where(mo => mo.Active == myStatus.Enabled);
```

But I have no idea how to include in this `DictList[mo.ID].Start();`

Comment: Why do you want this? There´s absoluetely no gain in using Linq here. Is just another syntax. Apart from this the Q in Linq stand for **querying**, not **modifying** or whatever you want to do in your `Start`.

Comment: You could just remove the explicit test inside the loop if you really think that this is more readable. No effective gain _foreach(MyObject mo in MyListOfObjects.Where(o => o.Active == myStatus.Enabled)) DictList[mo.ID].Start();_

Comment: *need to traverse...  is stored in Dictionary* well if your traversing a dictionary why is it in a Dictionary?

Comment: If you include a `Select(mo => DeictList[mo.ID])` then you can loop over that result and call your method `foreach(var x in r) x.Start();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great use of linq, but you could filter the list using linq then loop through it.

```
var itemsToStart = MyListOfObjects.Where(mo => mo.Active == myStatus.Enabled)
    .Select(mo=> DictList[mo]); //or ToList() if you intend to re-iterate 

foreach (var itemToStart in itemsToStart) {
    itemToStart.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anything at all, just remove the inner `if`

```
foreach (MyObject mo in MyListOfObjects.Where(x => x.Active == myStatis.Enabled))
{
     DictList[mo.ID].Start();
}
```

But that is *all* you should do - it is perfectly readable and maintainable.

Comment: Which is completely the same OP already has (despite from iterating).

Comment: @HimBromBeere of course it is, it just avoids a bit of nesting

Answer (score -2):

```
MyListOfObjects.Where(mo => mo.Active == myStatus.Enabled).ToList().ForEach(mo => DictList[mo.ID].Start());
```

`ForEach` is found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: `ForEach` is only on a list, so this wont even work. And there is no benefit converting to a list just to call `ForEach`

Comment: The built-in `ForEach` method is on `List<T>` , not on `IEnumerable<T>`, so this won't compile. A `ToList` call is needed, and it's questionable at best if that's a good option.

Comment: His object is called `MyListOfObjects` so I guess, it is a `List` :)

Comment: @Candide and when you call `Where(...)` you're turning it to an `IEnumerable<WhateverListWas>`

Comment: @Candide It may be, but you've called `Where` afterwards, which returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forget. I generally have my own extension for ForEach on IEnumerable<T>

Comment: Here's why there isn't a `ForEach` for `IEnumerable` https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: @juharr That's an argument but not one I agree with. "When we provide two subtly different ways to do exactly the same thing, we produce confusion in the industry." I am not confused. Come on, linq extensions in themselves shouldn't have been written in the first place if we were to agree with that statement.

Comment: Also should be noted that `ToList().ForEach` will first iterate the Linq query to create a intermediate list, then iterate that to call the code in the `ForEach` and throw away that list.

Comment: I know, but really, this guy is a new programmer. Do you really think that he is going to face any performance issues by iterating twice?

Comment: @Candide I think the bigger take away is that it is less readable and it's not just about if you are confused it's if another programmer that has to look at your code is.  You have to remember that half the reason for code is to express to other programmers what you're trying to do.